# Change colors using CSS on a bootstrap .collapsed selector

Tags: css, django, templates

Here is the important code in my Django template:

```
<a class="notibell" data-toggle="collapse" href="#pgsettings"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></a>

<div class="collapse" id="pgsettings">
  # content to show using the toggle anchor tag above.
</div>
```

I'm using this css in the page `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">

.notibell.collapsed { 
    color: green !important;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
}
.notibell { 
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
}

</style>
```

On page load, the icon color is red (should be green). Then on click, the color remains red (correct color for expanded div). And then another click and the color changes to green (correct color for collapsed div). Then from this point forward the toggle and colors change correctly.

The problem is on the page load, the color renders incorrectly despite the !important condition.

I've also tried loading css in the head before and after bootstrap loads, but this hasn't made a difference.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the code you posted the "`collapsed`" class-name isn't present on the element you're referring to, so the CSS shouldn't - by design - apply.

Comment: .collapsed is added to an element when using data-toggle="collapse" with bootstrap.

Comment: On page-load, or following interaction?

Comment: check out this: https://jsfiddle.net/qbmgr6su/

Comment: @ScottRoberts just add collapsed to your link - if that is the original state of your tab: `<a class="notibell collapsed" ` the js does not add it on page load - it only toggles it on click

Comment: @pete , ty. This solution works on page load and magically toggles.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the jquery toggle function to start it green and toggle back and forth to red.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp